# iOS simulator has no internet access

Tags: ios, xcode, proxy, ios7, ios-simulator

After updating to Xcode 5, the iOS simulator doesn't connect - not in Safari or Maps. It throws a "cache access denied" message.
Couldn't find anything online that solves it. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the simulator?

Comment: I have, multiple times. But nothing.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Found something that might be [relevant](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23264038#23264038)

Comment: I can't check now, but I'm pretty sure I am.

Comment: I tried cntlm, configured it and it still doesn't work. It is definitely a proxy issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just had the same problem in iOS Simulator Version 8.1 and this fixed it!

From the `menu bar`-> `iOS Simulator`-> `Reset Content and Settings...`

Answer (score 8):

The Avast Mac Security app is the culprit here. Launch Avast, go into Preferences > Shield, and disable Web Shield. Then restart the simulator and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it restarting iOS Simulator not reseting content and settings.

Comment: While not a great answer, it does provide an answer to a problem the poster considered the same issue.  Restarting, rebooting, or power cycling to resolve a problem is a valid solution to multiple problems.